# Problem with Deep Q-Network (python) and the train of the agent

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm currently trying to build a DQN agent using a helpful code I found from an online paper (Reinforcement Learning). I'm using TensorFlow 1.14.0.

I'm running the following code:

```
for _ in range(NN_UPDATES_PER_WARM_START):
    print('.', end='')
    # Sample a batch from the replay buffer proportionally to the probability of sampling.
    minibatch = replay_buffer.sample_minibatch(BATCH_SIZE)
    # Use batch to train an agent. Keep track of temporal difference errors during training.
    td_error = agent.train(minibatch)
    # Update probabilities of sampling each datapoint proportionally to the error.
    replay_buffer.update_td_errors(td_error, minibatch.indices)
```

But it raises an error in the td_error = agent.train(minibatch).

The error is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-867b2667a45e> in <module>()
      4     minibatch = replay_buffer.sample_minibatch(BATCH_SIZE)
      5     # Use batch to train an agent. Keep track of temporal difference errors during training.
----> 6     td_error = agent.train(minibatch)
      7     # Update probabilities of sampling each datapoint proportionally to the error.
      8     replay_buffer.update_td_errors(td_error, minibatch.indices)

/home/lazaioan/Desktop/RAL Codes/LAL-RL-Master-Original (copy 3)/dqn.py in train(self, minibatch, n_tensorboard)
   1009             feed_dict = {self.estimator.classifier_placeholder: minibatch.classifier_state,
   1010                 ######### self.estimator.action_placeholder: [minibatch.action_state[i] for i in range(len(minibatch.action_state))], #########
-> 1011                 self.estimator.action_placeholder: np.array(minibatch.action_state),
   1012                 self._next_best_prediction: max_prediction_batch,
   1013                 self._reward_placeholder: minibatch.reward,

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,8) into shape (3)
```

The train function is called from another .py file (dqn.py), and the lines where the problem occurs are the following (**in minibatch.action_state**):

```
_, loss, summ, _td_error = self.session.run(
    [self._train_op, self._loss, self.estimator.summaries, self._td_error],
    feed_dict = {self.estimator.classifier_placeholder: minibatch.classifier_state,
        self.estimator.action_placeholder: minibatch.action_state,
        self._next_best_prediction: max_prediction_batch,
        self._reward_placeholder: minibatch.reward,
        self._terminal_placeholder: minibatch.terminal,
        self.target_estimator.classifier_placeholder: minibatch.next_classifier_state,
        self.target_estimator.action_placeholder: minibatch.action_state
        })
```

Each element from minibatch is an array of shape 32 (it's also the same for me).

The problem is that in their code, minibatch.action_state has shape 3 (32 sun-arrays of 3 features each), for example every action is an array of 3 features, while I want every "action" to be a "batch of arrays of 3". So, for example, while minibatch.action_state[0] is shape (3,) in their paper, my minibatch.action_state[0] is shape (3,10) or (3,8) in another line.

For example, minibatch.action_state in THEIR PAPER is (dtype=array):

```
[[0.99286367, 0.9749906 , 0.97448924],
[0.36058693, 0.99352467, 0.9428495],
.....]
```

WHILE mibibatch.action_state in MY CODE (list of arrays) is:

```
[array([[0.04644732, 0.12056734, 0.36058693, 0.99352467, 0.9428495 ,
        0.01730469, 0.09757941, 0.32350904],
       [0.91286485, 0.90753378, 0.99761099, 1.0720428 , 1.07252544,
        0.90026116, 0.90931006, 0.95049693],
       [0.95847248, 0.99688911, 0.92369273, 1.16801097, 1.11937477,
        0.88151117, 0.96047654, 0.98909147]]), array([[0.53839238, 0.01215203, 0.93910424, 0.32661358, 0.14072223,
        0.04355487, 0.72415264, 0.75610243],
       [0.99404292, 1.02601031, 0.98186819, 1.00448436, 0.98644043,
        0.99286367, 0.9749906 , 0.97448924],
       [1.07852276, 0.87132646, 1.38006714, 0.70039993, 0.76713574,
        0.99388013, 1.35986748, 1.36584326]]), array([[0.21221239, 0.04032991, 0.99203309, 0.02040725, 0.83050092,
        0.41133832, 0.99203309, 0.16899745, 0.42542876, 0.8476126 ],
       [1.01898311, 0.91411494, 1.01929709, 0.95539219, 0.94656952,
        0.91259804, 1.01929709, 0.92619145, 0.91589772, 0.9621021 ],
       [1.14552466, 0.89210758, 0.99508556, 0.79885316, 0.86597793,
        0.8582233 , 0.99508556, 0.92626615, 0.84911241, 1.00648343]])
.....]
```

I want to pass a dynamic amount of actions in each round ( i.g. (3,10), next (3,8), next probably (3,10),. etc).

I think the problem is when building the DQN agent (initialization) (another .py file):

```
class Estimator: 
  
   def __init__(self, classifier_state_length, action_state_length, is_target_dqn, var_scope_name, bias_average):
     
       self.classifier_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, classifier_state_length], name="X_classifier")




       self.action_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, action_state_length], name="X_datapoint")




       with tf.variable_scope(var_scope_name):


           # A fully connected layers with classifier_placeholder as input
           fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
               inputs=self.classifier_placeholder,
               num_outputs=10,
               activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
               trainable=not is_target_dqn,
               variables_collections=[var_scope_name],
           )
           # Concatenate the output of first fully connected layer with action_placeholder
           fc2concat = tf.concat([fc1, self.action_placeholder], 1)
           # A fully connected layer with fc2concat as input
           fc3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
               inputs=fc2concat,
               num_outputs=5,
               activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid,
               trainable=not is_target_dqn,
               variables_collections=[var_scope_name]
           )
           # The last linear fully connected layer
           # The bias on the last layer is initialized to some value
           # normally it is the - average episode duriation / 2
           # like this NN find optimum better even as the mean is not 0
           self.predictions = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
               inputs=fc3,
               num_outputs=1,
               biases_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(bias_average),
               activation_fn=None,
               trainable=not is_target_dqn,
               variables_collections=[var_scope_name],
           )
```

I think that the problem is with the action_placeholder because in their code it has **shape=[None, action_state_length]** while in my code, I want it to be something like **shape=[None, action_state_length, None]** because I want 3 features in each run, but not just a single array.

Maybe I need to change the way they define the fully connected layers, but I would appreciate any ideas or helpful links.

Thank you.